# Is it possible to use TypeScript strictNullCheck as eslint rule?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have code base with errors which can be found by strictNullChecks.
But strictNullChecks compiler rule is only on/off.
I can't just fix/comment all problems to make TypeScript happy.
I want to raise warnings or eslint warnings for strict checks.

I tried to find applicable [rule in typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin) but I don't see any suitable.

Are there any possibilities to get strict TypeScript errors as eslint warnings?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this repo for this: https://github.com/JaroslawPokropinski/eslint-plugin-strict-null-checks.

Basically you can create a `tsconfig.eslint.json` which extends your main `tsconfig.json` and set up your eslint config to use it together with the plugin.
All the instructions are in the README.