# Is there a way to configure ESLint to catch bad use of null-like values in typescript?

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

For example, if I have this line of code:

```
const subject = collection.city?.person;

if(subject.name === "Jimmy") {
// do something
}
```

Static analysis tools yell at this line of code, for example, because they deem it "bad use of null-like values." Because if the subject is null, `subject.name` can't be defined. However, ESLint lets this go thru as a valid code.

Is there a way to configure ESLint to catch these types of errors before it gets to the static analysis tools at build time?

Comment: You may try [eslint-plugin-strict-null-checks](https://github.com/JaroslawPokropinski/eslint-plugin-strict-null-checks) as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71491028/11129751)

Comment: The optional chaining used in the code returns a null value instead of causing an error if the city is nullish. If you use `city.person` instead of `city?.person`, the static analysis tools won't be yell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69589969/eslint-activate-option-to-notify-object-is-possibly-null

Comment: Perhaps resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69589969/eslint-activate-option-to-notify-object-is-possibly-null

Answer (score 5):

You can use [TypeScript directly to enforce null checks, with `strictNullChecks` in your tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks):

> When `strictNullChecks` is `false`, `null` and `undefined` are effectively ignored by the language. This can lead to unexpected errors at runtime.
>
> When `strictNullChecks` is `true`, `null` and `undefined` have their own distinct types and you’ll get a type error if you try to use them where a concrete value is expected.

This will work much more effectively than ESLint's null enforcement, as it runs in the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: I believe I have this enabled in tsConfig via `"strict": true,` and it's still not catching this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

check the eslint-plugin-strict-null-checks plugin.

https://github.com/JaroslawPokropinski/eslint-plugin-strict-null-checks

The description quoted from the github repo

> Eslint plugin that aims to reproduce strictNullChecks from tsconfig for easier migration and for projects that prefer to have it as a warning not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe what type `collection` has, or better playground example.
As with proper typing, TS will throw error on `subject.name` complaining subject can be undefined

check here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrIN4Chm+Q4MATwH4AuTAB2gGcB7ECjEOAWwgprClAHMBffliEIGXfHQA2kiAjDAGyCumQBeTEKyiQ4mgFcARgCtZYNROmmFIAHQFiJG9Sj0QAbixZgMABT7jpjYs7Gqq6gBEAFLArKxE4QCUmFgA9CnIACZ0yPTsYAAWfMJYQA

ESLint is not the tool for such checks, as deriving type of `subject` could be super complicated, and you'll basically end up with trying to implement in ESLint the same things what TS compiler does.

What you can do is run TS in 'check' mode alognside with ESLint. so it will not compile code but instead check it and fail same way as ESLint does it's check. this can be used as a CI step or commit/push hook. tsc --noEmit does the trick, with possible additional parameters depending on your case.